# Django & Python unittest - find a Div Class

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, beautifulsoup

I am writing a test in python and for one part, using Beautiful Soup I want to check that it has gone to a specific page by looking for a certain Div:Class.

The line in my test is:

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)
    check_tag = len(soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'booking-test'}))
    self.assertEqual(check_tag, 1)
```

When I run the test it returns the FAIL message:

```
self.assertEqual(check_tag, 1)
AssertionError: 0 != 1
```

Is this the correct way to test for a specific Div?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax works for BeautifulSoup 4.3.1. With 3.2.1 it only works if your div *only* has this class (ie it fails on `div class="booking-test other">`

NB : not tested with other versions but I assume it's a matter of 3.x / 4.x